# C# Web Form Processing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm rather new to using C#, and I've run into an issue with using C# to handle form data once a button is clicked. Basically what I am trying to do is capture the user's information once the form button is clicked, assign it to a session and then display it on another page. Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class Data : Page
{
    protected void btnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = Request.Form["username"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            // string usr_err = "You did not supply a username???";
            return;
        }

        // make the string uppercase
        string upperCase = name.ToUpper();

        string greeting = "Welcome " + upperCase + "! Did you know that October is called Oktober in German?";

        Session["username"] = upperCase;
        Session["greeting"] = greeting;

        Response.Redirect("test.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

And this is my html (login.apsx):

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Data.cs" Inherits="CS" %>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .form-control {
            border: thin solid #000;
        }

        #main-col {
            border-radius: 20px;
            border: thin solid #000;
            padding: 20px;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            color: rgba(50, 99, 149, 1);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" data-role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><p class="navbar-text navbar-left" style="color: #000;"><b> Login</b></p></li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-center"><br><br><br>Manipulating data server side<br><br><br></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div clas="row-fluid">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3" id="main-col">
                <form id="login" runat="server">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username here" runat="server" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password here" runat="server" />
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Button id="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit" runat="server" />

                    </div> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running into this compilation error though and I have no idea why:

```
Line 2:  using System.Web.UI;

Line 3:  

Line 4:  public partial class Data : Page

Line 5:  {

Line 6:      protected void btnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)

(Line 4 is where the error occurs).
```

If this helps, here is some more details about it via the compiler:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in
>   this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends
>   the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl)

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error message as below, it correctly states what's the problem.

> Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in
>   this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends
>   the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl)

Your `Inherit` attribute which is currently `CodeFile="Data.cs" Inherits="CS"` should be pointed to `Data` as well like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Data.cs" Inherits="Data" %>
```

(OR) if you have defined a namespace then qualify with that namespace like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Data.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.Data" %>
```

Comment: I just saw that too. Thanks :)